# using Crontab to run simple Python file

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am trying to run a simple Python script with crontab, but I can’t get it to work. I can run a simple program in crontab when not using Python though. Here is the line I have in my Crontab file that does work:

```
* * * * * echo “cron test” >> /home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows/hello.txt
```

I also can run this python script testit.py directly from the command line. This is my testit.py file that outputs a csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import f_file_handling
_data = [(12,15,17)]
f_file_handling.csv_out('my_file_test',_data)
```

The above file has a function I made, but I know it works since it does what I expect when I run the testit.py from the command line like this:

```
python testit.py
```

So I got Crontab to work on it's own and the testit.py file to work on it's own then I tried to run the testit.py file with Crontab.
I did make the testit.py file executable with command:

```
chmod +x testit.py
```

And I see its executable because the file shows up in green in my linux command window when I’m in the proper directory.
Now in the same Crontab file I used to run the earlier Crontab test I added the following line:

```
* * * * * /home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows/testit.py
```

Yes, I am tying to get this to execute every minute, just trying to run the simplest test possible to get Crontab and Python to work together.

Here is what I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)
- Python 2.7

The above are on a linux server I have set up.

You see the shebang line at the top of my testit.py file, from my research this should work.
As far as my testit.py python file, I wrote it on a windows machine and then transferred it to the server, but when crontab and python did not work together I also coded the file from the Linux command window using Nano text editor, but this makes no difference when trying to run the testit.py file through Crontab. So it does not run even when I write the testit.py code directly on the Linux server (just in case windows created hidden characters in my file).

Comment: Can you post the line in your crontab that actually calls the python script?

Comment: the line that actually runs the python script is:

Comment: the line that actually runs the python script is:   * * * * * /home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows/testit.py

Comment: I notice you have "Chmod +x testit.py". I'm not sure if this has any effect either, but generally Chmod is not capitalized, and is instead "chmod". Think you can give that a try?

Comment: your right, but i accidentally capitalized when asking question. Thanks though zavtra

Comment: cron is wonky when it comes to path and variables.  I see the hard-coded path in the crontab file, maybe you should try renaming the shebang from the environment checking /usr/bin/env to the full path of the python instance? (/usr/bin/python on my 14.04.2). Or even more precisely change the crontab to "/usr/bin/python <fullpathofscript>" instead of depending on the shebang at all.

Comment: Another thing to check is to try another python script that just prints "hello" and redirect that to a file (as in the echo).  That way you can see if it is a problem in the execution of the python code in the cron environment or problem with cron initiating execution of the code.

Comment: And thing to try is to add ". $HOME/.profile; " to the front of the execution line to set up your home environment as in this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables

Comment: thanks dhj - will try these suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- cron runs commands in a limited environment. Only a few environment variables
  are automatically set. It loads the environment specified by `/etc/environment`
  and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, but not about the environment variables you
  might have set in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

  Set the crontab entry

  ```
  *   *    *    *    *   /usr/bin/env > /tmp/out
  ```

  to take a look at what environment variables are actually set.
  Don't forget to remove the crontab entry once you have /tmp/out.
- When running Python scripts, one important environment variable that you would
  probably need to set is PYTHONPATH. So at the top of your crontab add a
  PYTHONPATH setting such as:

  ```
  PYTHONPATH=/home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows
  ```

  Be sure to add the directory which contains the `f_file_handling` module so
  Python will find the module when it runs the statement

  ```
  import f_file_handling
  ```
- Finally, also note that cron [runs commands in your home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38956/3330) by default. 
  It would be better to be explicit however, and supply a full path whenever you specify a file in your script:

  ```
  f_file_handling.csv_out('/path/to/my_file_test',_data)
  ```

Comment: thank you, this is awesome information. I have done your suggestions and  i still am not having success -- when i add your crontab entry ending in /tmp/out and then open that file it shows me this:  Home=/root   LOGNAME=root   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin   LANG=en_US.UTF-8   SHELL=/bin/sh    PWD=/root    PYTHONPATH=/home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows

Comment: thank you, this is what worked : f_file_handling.csv_out('/path/to/my_file_test',_data)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I've always successfully managed to get python scripts to run successfully from cron by adding this line to the end of the crontab file:

```
@reboot python /home/ftpuser/dev/mod_high_lows/testit.py &
```

The `&` is necessary at the end of the line. If this is what you need, and you would like for this script to execute every minute, you could put the whole script in a loop and then put a one minute sleep at the end of each loop's iteration.

You may also need to put a `sudo` before the python, although crontabs should run as root anyway so this probably won't be necessary. This method has worked for running scripts on boot up for my Raspberry Pi though.

Comment: I added that line at the very end of my crontab tab file exactly as you wrote it, so i have my orginal crontab command starting with * * * * * and the one you gave me at the end (also tried "sudo"). Still no luck, but i will play around with this. Thanks

Comment: Did you reboot after adding the line?

Comment: I just closed out of my server and then logged back in (thats what you mean by reboot right?)  then went to directory  and i see that it still did not work, my testit.py file still has not created csv file  - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One thing that always gets me: You have to leave a blank line at the end of the crontab file. Cron will not run the last line of the crontab!